# Ads not showing but Test ads shown properly and also request are made but no impression

Tags: ios, admob, google-contacts-api

I am using Google Admob to show interstitial ads and rewarded ads in my iOS app. It has been live and was working properly but from last three weeks it is not working. There are many request for ads but showing 0 impression.

When I debug my code with my live ids, I am having error `Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show.` Test ads are working fine.

I have checked my Admob account also and status showing Active.

Comment: Did you find any solution , in my app its working with test id but with real id it never show the ads , while for other app its working fine